# How to Emulate High Res displays for Web layout issues

Tags: html, css, layout, emulation

I have website which is having layout issues on certain devices which I believe I've tracked down to high res displays which also have the display scaling in windows 10 set to 200%. (not 200% in the browser, but in the display settings in the Windows Control Panel)

The problem is I don't have a device which can duplicate the resolution of these devices, which is 2736 x 1824 (it's a MS Surface Pro).  Oh yeah, this only happen with Edge...

I know of sites which have VMs which will run different browsers for testing purposes, but I don't know of any which allow you to choose your resolution.  Without going out and getting a hold of this specific machine, how else can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out none of the emulation/scaling options in the dev console would emulate what was really happening.  I ended up remoting into the customer's computer so I could do my own debugging on there and resolved the issue.

Seems like Edge v 44 was computing some CSS calc function for a div height incorrectly (off by 1 or 2 pixels) which was making some divs push out and mess up the layout.

The fix was to tweak the CSS so the calculation wasn't required.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom device in the developer console, and simply display it at whatever scale actually fits on your screen. For instance, create a custom device with that particular resolution, then in the developer console on Chrome you can view it scaled down 50% (if your own resolution is 1920x1080) so that the whole thing is visible.

Comment: I worthy try, but it ended up having a different effect than changing the display scaling in windows.  Seems like something in edge was calculating pixels incorrectly, and a layout was pushed off to the side when the Windows display scaling was at 200%.